# RunTime Error : map/set iterators incompatible

Tags: c++, iterator, runtime-error

I have a runtime error "map/set iterators incompatible" at line 8.

```
void Manager::Simulate(Military* military, Shalishut* shalishut,char* args[]){
    Simulation* simulation = Simulation::GetInstance();
    Time* time = Time::GetInstance();

    multimap<int,Task*>::iterator itTasks;
    itTasks = simulation->GetTasks().begin();
    while(itTasks != simulation->GetTasks().end()){
      while (itTasks->second->GetTimeStamp() == time->GetTime()){ /*line 8 - ERROR*/
            TaskExecute(itTasks->second,military,shalishut,args);
            itTasks++;
        }
        // Unit take car of vehicles
        time->TimeIncrease();
    }

}
```

`Simulation` is declared as a `multimap<int,Task*>`. What is the problem?

Comment: Could you reformat you code so it is readable and specify the language you are talking about in the tags? It would help you get an answer much quicker.

Comment: `Simulation` is not a multimap - multimaps do not have a `GetTasks()` member function.

Answer (score 22):

I'm going to take a wild guess and say that the `Simulation::GetTasks()` signature looks like this:

```
multimap<int,Task*> GetTasks() const;
```

This creates a new multimap (a *copy*) each time you call it.

When comparing iterators, both of the `multimap<int,Task*>` iterators must come from the same container; since you're getting a new copy each time you call `GetTasks()`, you violate this constraint, and this is the source of your error. You also have another problem - the temporary multimap copies are destroyed after the statement they're created in, so your iterators are invalidated instantly.

You have two choices; one is to capture a copy locally and use that copy consistently:

```
multimap<int,Task*> tasks = simulation->GetTasks();
multimap<int,Task*>::iterator itTasks;
itTasks = tasks.begin();
while(itTasks != tasks.end()){
  while (itTasks->second->GetTimeStamp() == time->GetTime()){
        TaskExecute(itTasks->second,military,shalishut,args);
        itTasks++;
    }
    // Unit take car of vehicles
    time->TimeIncrease();
}
```

Another is to have `GetTasks()` return a reference to a *persistent* multimap, ensuring the same one is used each time:

```
multimap<int,Task*> &GetTasks();
```

Or a const reference:

```
const multimap<int,Task*> &GetTasks() const;
```

This has the advantage of avoiding the (potentially large) overhead of copying the `multimap`.

Note that using a const reference requires using `const_iterator`s to step through the multimap. I would recommend defining both const and non-const accessors (C++ will pick the right one based on if the `Simulation` pointer or reference is const), unless you want to disallow direct modification of the underlying `multimap` entirely, in which case you can define only the `const` variant.

Comment: This is the solution my problem. Returned a std::multimap by a member as a non reference